# PHP read csv and load it into postgres with PDO

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have `.csv` file with 9k rows. When I use script from `php manual` :

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

I got on my `output` everysingle cell from the `csv` file.

Problem occurs when I want to treat every row as record create object from it and store it into database. I have modified it like:

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        $record= new Record($db);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $record->$attributes[$c] =  utf8_encode($data[$c]);
        }
    $record->Store();
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

In this case only about 2k records are store into mine `PostgreSQL` database, but no exception or error is shown. I have no idea why my loop stops. Everytime i run the script it loads into mine database different amount of records between 1,6k and 2,1k.

I have no limits set on my `PostgreSQL` (At least i don't knew of any..)

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `copy` statement. I belive it is similar to `MySql LOAD DATA IN FILE`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

If it's just the data you need to add, it would be considerably faster that any other method.

Answer (score 1):

Two Things here I will change 
A. change the !== FALSE)  to  !=false), don't ask me why , it sometimes work
B. do NOT NEW you record instance in the loop without unset it , you are creating 2000 new instance so that may be the reason.